# Angular 2 routing only works in ng serve but not nodemon

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I'm currently developing angular 2 application. But i'm having a hard time understanding why my routing on works in `ng serve` and not in `nodemon`? I've tried out multiple method based on what i've research on but they dont really works like how i thought it would be. (Probably due to my poor understanding)

**Method 1**

Adding `useHash: true` in the `app-routing.module.ts` But this would cause all the URL to have `#` appear in it. And i'm thinking this is meant for debugging purposes right?

```
const routes = [
{ path: '', component: sampleComponent1 },
{ path: 'page2', component: sampleComponent2 }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**Method 2**

Change `app.js` to render `index` whenever error is thrown. This method would not have `#` in URL but it will always return error like `GET /page2 404 1.688 ms - 987` in my console.

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
   // set locals, only providing error in development
   console.log(err.message);
   res.locals.message = err.message;
   res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

   res.status(err.status || 500);
   res.render('error');
});
```

So as of now, I'm sticking more to method 2 as the URL does not show `#` in it, but i'm not sure if method 2 is the correct way to do it. Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: `useHash` isn't just for debugging. It is a design choice.

Comment: Have you tried to ng build and then serving your dist folder with nodemon ?

Comment: @Janpan Yes, i'll always do a ng build before running nodemon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this works in development with the Angular CLI is that all routes that don't exist get served as index.html

This allows your Angular application to handle all the routing regardless of what URL was actually requested. Once your application is started in the browser the Angular router (assuming that's what you're using) will read the route information and display the correct route to your user.

There are other answers on here that explain this solution as well depending upon your web server.

Comment: This sounds similar to what I did in method 2 right? SInce it always get an error 404 whenever I request for a page e.g. `localhost/page2` and the index.html will get served